# Optimizing the hive query :Apache Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, query-tuning

The following hive query which finds the lead and lag on a single column. The query spawns 1 Mapper and 50 Reducers. How can i optimize the query to spawn less reduces.

Table description

```
col_name        data_type       comment
# col_name              data_type               comment

a                       int
```

Data in tale

```
 select * from foo;
OK

 foo.a 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 6 78 9 7 NULL
```

---

```
select lag(a,1) over (order by a) as next,lead(a,1) over (order by a) as prev from foo;
```

> Query ID =
>   phodisvc_20170403015502_de129135-eb19-4c4d-8161-c3f217a45928 Total
>   jobs = 1 Launching Job 1 out of 1 Number of reduce tasks not
>   specified. Defaulting to jobconf value of: 50 In order to change the
>   average load for a reducer (in bytes):   set
>   hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer= In order to limit the
>   maximum number of reducers:   set hive.exec.reducers.max= In
>   order to set a constant number of reducers:   set
>   mapreduce.job.reduces= Kill Command =
>   /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/bin/hadoop job  -kill
>   job_1489146839620_136214 Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of
>   mappers: 1; number of reducers: 50

Comment: what is file the Type?

Comment: Example: ORC, RCFILE, TEXTFILE .. etc

Comment: Please share `show create table mytable;`and `show table extended like mytable;`

Comment: And check `mapreduce.job.reduces`

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz setting this parameter mapreduce.job.reducers worked for me. Thanks!!

Comment: Setting it is the obvious, the interesting part here is why you got 50 reducers in the first place. Was this parameter set to 50?